# merge two branches in third

Tags: mercurial

I have 2 users with 2 branches (b1 and b2) on the same project. Each user works with own branch. When I try to merge these together, let's say, in "stable" branch - I have no effect.

Now I'm in my own branch (b1), and do this:

```
hg branch stable //As I can understand - this is creates new branch, named "stable"
hg commit 
hg push //To make affect to bitbucket.
```

So, at this moment, "stable" and "b1" is the same thing. Am I right?
Next I should merge b2 and stable. I do this:

```
hg branch //to make shure, that I'm in "stable"
hg merge b2
hg commit
hg push
```

BUT! After that, if I type `hg update b2` mercurial tells me, that 33 files updated! Branches are not, actually, merged!

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the graph of your repository it will look something like this.

```
B1     o----o---B1
                  \
Stable             o----S
                       /
B2     o----o---o----B2
```

- `S` is the revision `hg update stable` will take you to.
- `B1` is the revision `hg update b1` will take you to.
- `B2` is the revision `hg update b2` will take you to.

`hg branches` will give you a list of the heads of each branch.

When you update to `b2` you're moving back to the pre-merge version. It perfectly permissible to:

```
hg update b2
<do some work>
hg commit
```

...and you'll end up with:

```
B1     o----o---B1
                  \
Stable             o----S
                       /
B2     o----o---o-----o----B2
```

Similarly you could continue using `b1`

Think of it like this. You were in `stable` and merged the changes in `b2` into `stable`, but you didn't merge `stable` into `b2`. The `b2` branch was unmodified.

Comment: I merge B2 into stable, but mercurial reports me about 1 changed file. In the mean time, B2 have 33 files that differs from stable. Mercurial ignore that files, I don't know why. I can write here some output from hg, but after all my experiments, I'm afraid it is no such good idea... =)

Comment: It sounds like you've gotten yourself into a mess. `hg branches` and `hg log -G` are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

1. Additional branch is useless - you can always use existing "default"
2. Before real merge, compare branches heads with diff in order to see changes (and show diff here, if needed and full merges output also)

Common merge workflow will be

- `hg up default`
- `hg merge b1`
- ... resolve conflicts, if needed
- `hg commit -m "Merged b1"`
- `hg merge b2`
- ... resolve conflicts, if needed
- `hg commit -m "Merged b2"`